# Confusion occurring between static and non static members

Tags: class, static

```
    class equation
 {

  int xc, yc, zc, c;
  static float x,y,z;
  public:
    void getValues()
    {
         cout<<"Enter the coefficeint of x";
         cin>>xc;
         cout<<"Enter the coefficeint of y";
         cin>>yc;
         cout<<"Enter the coefficeint of z";
         cin>>zc;
         cout<<"Enter the value of c";
         cin>>c;
    }
    void update()
    {
        x = -(y*yc + z*zc + c)/xc;
        y = -(x*xc + z*zc + c)/yc;
        z = -(y*yc + x*xc + c)/zc;
    }
    void putValues()
    {
        cout<<"The value of x is : "<<x;
        cout<<"The value of y is : "<<y;
        cout<<"The value of z is : "<<z;
       }
   };
    float equation::x = 0.0;
   float equation::y = 0.0;
    float equation::z = 0.0;
```

I am using the code to implement gauss seidel method using classes and not getting correct output. I think there is some problem accessing static members, please help me out

Comment: What is the actual and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're having trouble because you're dividing by an int without converting to floating point rather than due to static vs dynamic. Are you able to provide some input and output that is incorrect? Alternately can you define your ints as float? Better yet use double.

Comment: I made the change that you suggested.. but still the code is behaving the same way

Answer (score 0):

What values are you entering that are giving incorrect answers? If I'm going to help further I'd like to at least know what your test data is.